# What is the best approach to pull SMS specific data and auto parse it in another app?

Tags: android, sms, sms-retriever-api

Every month, I need to manually take note of each bank transaction, so I would manage my expenses and savings. This is a day to day time-consuming problem.

> I have done some research, but as a community, you might have been
>   through this in your experience or maybe a similar case to solve this
>   problem. If not, your comments and opinions are appreciated.

.

> This is the tried manual task with every received bank SMS
>   transaction:

**listonic Android app** was used to manually take note of paid transaction price number of the received bank SMS message and update(increment) paid transaction price number in a note format in case of every newly received SMS from that bank) **manual and ineffective solution**

**The research I conducted and proposed solutions:**

1- Writing code to automatically pull price number from SMS transaction and match price number based on currency (e.g 10$ of food) and parse this value (10$) conditioned to auto-increment in case of every new received SMS message with a transaction value from the same bank name. The below sites could achieve this use case. [How to extract data from a received sms and use it in another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948676/how-to-extract-data-from-a-received-sms-and-use-it-in-another-activity) and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzWYv8y2v1c

2- It is not worth coding time and there is an alternative

3- Utilize macro script

**A proposed script of solution number 1:**

Pulling data:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    byte[] pdu = new byte[0]; //obviously use the real pdu in your app
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("smsPdu", pdu);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Parsing data

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        byte[] pdu = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("smsPdu");
        SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
}
```

**Solution Outcome:**
Automating the task of pulling data from specified SMS provider and parse that data into an object with the condition of auto parsing in case of new SMS is received from the specified SMS provider. Example: so if I received SMS with the value of 10$ and 2nd SMS was 20$, I automatically see the pulled data which is the number 30$ parsed in Google Keep or listonic or any app. The final number matters, so I would balance my expenses and savings

**Benefits:**
This will allow not just me to see up to date value of my expenses, but also save time and energy or repetitive similar activities sent via SMS.

Opening doors for SMS automation (IR 4.0)

No need to pay for apps since the need is the mother of invention

Thank you

Comment: To make it easier for others to answer your long question and digest, I would suggest splitting it up into a bit more sections. Also, just like you did for the "Solution Outcome" and "Benefits", please include a "Question" that is the summarized question (might as well use your title as it is).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure whether this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com than here; perhaps someone more experienced can shed some light on the matter.